# auto-login powerbi service from custom application

Tags: javascript, java, powerbi

I am very new to the powerbi world and have to take care of simple integration. I need my custom java/ javascript application to integrate with powerbi. I want to support auto-login for app.powerbi.com

The use-case is this. The user logs into my application with the credentials owned and managed by my application. Once they are logged in, there is a place on the UI which will redirect them to app.powerbi.com. What I want is that the user seamlessly logs into app.powerbi.com without providing the credentials again i.e auto-login.

I couldn't find such an API. As you may see this is not a PowerBI embedded use-case - I saw APIs for that but those do not seem to work in this case.  I simply need to redirect the user to app.powerbi.com and not want them to supply credentials there.

Please guide me in this regard. Is there an API available that supports auto-login i.e I get a ticket first for powerbi and then supply that ticket with the redirect link to log in the user.

Comment: Welcome. SO is not meant to do the job for you. Instead, focus on a specific technical problem.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain the question is to seek help from exp. powerbi devs who may have seen a similar help. I am not asking for code but a pointer to the API/ documentation which I couldn't find after much browsing.

Comment: You will not find such API, because Power BI doesn't trust your app. Your credentials worths nothing. Power BI uses Azure AD for authentication. Period. Either embed it, or change your app's authentication to use Azure AD with SSO.